# Installing python-twisted on yocto

Tags: linux, twisted, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have successfully built the yocto core-image-sato and that went well.  Now I am trying to add a recipe to the build.  I want to install python-twisted, but am failing miserably.

I found that python-twisted doesn't seem to be available in yocto, but is in openembedded.  So I cloned the openembedded repo from here:

http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/

I then added the necessarily directories to bblayers.conf as such:

```
BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/git/poky/meta \
  /home/git/poky/meta-yocto \
  /home/git/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/git/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/git/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  "
```

When I parse the recipes with bitbake -p, I get the following error:

```
Loading cache: 100% |###########################################| ETA:  00:00:00
Loaded 765 entries from dependency cache.                                       
ERROR: ParseError at /home/git/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/networkmanager/networkmanager_1.0.10.bb:12: Could not inherit file classes/bash-completion.bbclass                                                           

Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried deleting the file in question since I doubt I need it, but that lead to worse errors.

I have no idea where to go from here.  I suspect the issue might be that the files I get from openembedded don't match the files yocto project.   But I don't know what to do about that.

Any help on how to add python-twisted to core-image-sato would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, rule number one when using OpenEmbedded-based build systems, make sure that all your layers use the correct branch!

Look at the `README` in each additional layer that you want to use. That `README` should specify what other layers are required, and which branches from those required layers.

`bash-completion.bbclass` was recently added to OE-Core (end of January, 2016). Thus, it's only part of the master branch, no releases incorporate that class.

The `networkmanager_1.0.10.bb` is only available in the master branch of `meta-openembedded`. I assume you're using the `jethro` release of poky (2.0), together with the master branch of `meta-openembedded`. Please, fix that.

As a side note, if you had incorporated the layer info that you get when you run `bitbake`, it would have been much easier to help you.

Comment: That was exactly it.  jethro on poky and master on oe.  I didn't know they used the same branch names.  Did a jethro checkout on oe and everything parsed fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Added a small section on the `README` in additional layers.

Answer (score 0):

File not found error, the bb file networkmanager_1.0.10.bb is not able to inherit file under classes as mentioned in the error.

solution:
If you are trying to copy a recipe from open embedded try to copy all the dependent files and modify according to the yocto.
In your case

```
inherit gnomebase gettext systemd bluetooth bash-completion vala gobject-introspection
```

`bash-completion.bbclass` is missing in the classes. Due to this the parse error is coming.

Try to add oe-core/classes where you can find the bbclass

This can be found in `openembedded-core/meta/classes/`
https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/tree/master/meta/classes

Comment: Attempting this can lead to a deep rabbit hole of interconnected dependencies and assumptions: far simpler to use the jethro branch of meta-oe if the submitter is using the jethro release of oe-core.

Comment: @RossBurton thank you for your suggestion, your right.